# django error while using foreignkey in multiple models of single model

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Register(models.Model):
    seeker_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    seeker_email = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    seeker_password = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.seeker_name

class Details(models.Model):
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user = models.ForeignKey(access_models.Register, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candidate_details', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(str):
        return self.name

class Social(models.Model):
    social_links = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user = models.ForeignKey(access_models.Register, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candidate_details', null=True, blank=True)
```

errors:

```
    django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

    ERRORS:
    details.CandidateDetails.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'CandidateDetails.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Social.user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'CandidateDetails.user' or 'Social.user'.
    details.CandidateDetails.user: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'CandidateDetails.user' clashes with reverse query name for 'Social.user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'CandidateDetails.user' or 'Social.user'.
    details.Social.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Social.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'CandidateDetails.user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Social.user' or 'CandidateDetails.user'.
    details.Social.user: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Social.user' clashes with reverse query name for 'CandidateDetails.user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Social.user' or 'CandidateDetails.user'.

    System check identified 4 issues (0 silenced).
```

Here I want to use `ForeignKey` both in `Details` and `Social` for `Register` model.
but it is giving me above error.

please have a look into my code.

Comment: related_name `candidate_social`  is duplicate and you are using this name in another relation to User model, change `related_name` of user field in Social model, it will work

Answer (score 1):

Change the `related_name` in your `Social` model.

```
class Social(models.Model):
    social_links = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user = models.ForeignKey(access_models.Register, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candidate_social', null=True, blank=True)
```

Also If you are storing URLs you may want to consider using [URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) which does basic validations for URLs.

Comment: @soubhagya If it solved your problem please consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer to help the future readers.